How do I use Streams in .Net to unpack data without duplicating the data
I have this inherited code:
private string DecompressData(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] decompressedData;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            using (MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                gzip.CopyTo(resultStream);
                decompressedData = resultStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedData);
}

The data array can be up to 1Mb, and the zip ratio can get up to 32x its seems. However I am seeing big jumps in memory usage (around 100Mb sometimes) from this method. It is part of a container task that I am trying to parallelize as much as possible to get the most out of each container, but currently seeing OOM errors. How can I rewrite this code so that the input data is disposed of as the next stream reads it? Or what different approach can I take to do the same task in a more memory efficient way?

@Itallmakescents - 100 mb of contiguous data (such as a string or byte array) can be a problem.  It will go on the large object heap which can lead to fragmentation.

@Josh - how long is the string you are decompressing?  Longer than 42,500 characters?  If so, it will go on the large object heap which can lead to fragmentation and thus OOM errors.  Do you really need such a large string?  What are you using the string for?  And where did the byte array come from?  Was that originally from some stream?  is it larger than 85,000 bytes?

you actually have three copies of the uncompressed data here; the MemoryStream's buffer, the array from ToArray, and the string (which will generally take twice as much space as the array, because UTF16). Using a RecyclableMemoryStream and the TryGetBuffer etc API can remove the first two costs, but a large string is still a large string!

Thanks @MarcGravell will look into that.

@dbc the byte array can go very large, have seen over 600,000. There is temptation to rearchitect for sure, I'm just trying to optimise as much as possible before using a bigger stick

I second the suggestion to use RecyclableMemoryStream instead of the original byte [] array.  And returning a StringBuilder rather than a fully materialized string might prevent some OOM errors as well since StringBuilder uses chunks.  But what are you using the string for?  Is it JSON or XML or HTML?

@dbc, thanks I'll look into RecycleableMemoryStream. The resulting string is Json yes. Thats another issue, deserializing the json causes a big jump in memory as well.

Every major JSON serializer can deserialize directly from a stream, you don't need the string representation at all.  For instance, if you are using Newtonsoft, see Can I decompress and deserialize a file using streams?. (Answer: yes.) That entirely eliminates the intermediate strings and byte arrays.  What serializer are you using?  And is your root JSON container an array or an object?

Awesome I'll give that a go too and report back. I'm using the microsoft one, and it deserializes into a list of objects

If your root JSON container is an array, you can stream through the file in chunks by using JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable().  See e.g. Performance issue with deserializing large JSON file into objects and add them to database.  Combine that with Rowan Smith's answer to read directly from a compressed stream using new GZipStream(jsonStream, CompressionMode.Decompress) and you should be able to resolve your memory issues.

Also, where did the original byte [] array come from?  From a file stream or httpClient stream?

Good point, it came from a stream as well. I'll provide that stream directly to avoid writing to byte array in the first place, though the benefits of that will probably be minimal since the compressed data is only 600Kb. I can't seem to find DeserializeAsyncEnumerable(), though the docs say it's part of System.Text.Json. I'm running .Net 8, it shouldn't need a package installed should it? I'm a bit rusty on this but I assume it will prove an async enumerable so that things are only deserialized as needed?

Scratch missing package comment, brain fart - Monday things

Hmm, at this point you might want to ask another question showing your entire problem.  Rowan Smith's answer gives the best possible answer to the problem shown in your question, which is decompressing a byte array to a string without using huge intermediate buffers.

As suggested I have made a bigger question with much more context. Already my problem is massively improved so thank you everyone for the help, especially @dbc
New question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79221507/how-do-i-efficiently-deserialize-a-compressed-list-of-objects-add-to-it-and-co

Could try something like this to see if it uses less memory:
private string DecompressData(byte[] data)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
    using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(gzip, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        // Read directly from the GZipStream and decode into a string
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

This way you are not copying it into an intermediate memory stream.

Thanks for the suggestion. Tried this out with a 600Kb original data array, unpacked (I saved to disk to see size) it is 22Mb, and memory jumps to 106Mb. Seems to be an improvement from original which jumped to 150ish Mb, so thanks for that. Hoping for a solution in the end which just uses the 22Mb I need
